# MySQL "NOT LIKE" query with multiple wildcards

Tags: mysql, wildcard, sql-like

I am looking for an easier way to perform a multiple-wildcard NOT LIKE query.

```
SELECT * from table 
  WHERE name NOT LIKE 'a1%' 
    AND name NOT like 'a2%'
    AND name not like 'a3%' .... etc
```

I need to match `NOT LIKE A{number}%` through to `F{number}%` (removing anything starting with `[a-f]`, followed by a number, from my search results).

I have tried various combinations of

```
AND name NOT LIKE '[a-f][0-9]%'
```

but, with no success.

Comment: try `not regexp` instead of `not like`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp` instead of `like` in mysql, try this:

`select * from table where name not regexp '^[a-f][0-9]'`

quick demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5630/1

Comment: Man `a-f` is range but OP asked to exlude only `a` and `f` followed by number

Comment: no, he did not ask that. `removing anything starting with a-f `

Comment: Sorry pala_ I will clarify -- Anything starting with a followed by a number to f followed by a number. I presumed based on explaining it a few times different ways it would be clear.

Comment: Yes. That it is what my query should match. A0, a1, ..., b0, b1, ... F9. Or 160 to 249 if they're hex values